# pigpio.error: 'no permission to update GPIO' (again)

Tags: pi-3b+

I am a beginner in Python and in the Raspberry field. I want to write a code to drive 3 leds with a PWM signal. The three leds must not emit at the same time and I want them to emit pulses trains. In order to do that, I triggered the driving signals for the three leds on the rising edge of a fourth PWM signal name "clock".

Firstly I write a code with the RPi library and it worked quite well. But for a frequency above 1 kHz, the Raspberry doesn't generate a clean signal. This is why I want to use the pigpio library.

Thus, I modified my previous code to adapt it to the pigpio library. The code is the following :

```
import pigpio
import time


pi = pigpio.pi()

clock=11

led_1=35

led_2=32

led_3=33



pi.set_mode(12, pigpio.OUTPUT)

pi.set_mode(clock, pigpio.INPUT)

pi.set_mode(led_1, pigpio.OUTPUT)

pi.set_mode(led_2, pigpio.OUTPUT)

pi.set_mode(led_3, pigpio.OUTPUT)


pi.set_PWM_frequency(clock, 10)

pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(clock, 128)

pi.set_PWM_frequency(led_1, 2000)

pi.set_PWM_frequency(led_2, 10)

pi.set_PWM_frequency(led_3, 10)



pi.wait_for_edge(clock)

pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_1, 0)

pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_2, 0)

pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_3, 0)


while(1) :

        pi.wait_for_edge(clock)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_1, 25)
        pi.wait_for_edge(clock,FALLING_EDGE)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_1, 0)

        pi.wait_for_edge(clock)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_2, 25)
        pi.wait_for_edge(clock,FALLING_EDGE)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_2, 0)


        pi.wait_for_edge(clock)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_2, 25)
        pi.wait_for_edge(clock,FALLING_EDGE)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_2, 0)


        pi.wait_for_edge(clock)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_3, 25)
        pi.wait_for_edge(clock,FALLING_EDGE)
        pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_3, 0)
```

When I run the program with sudo, it returns to me this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "led_train_2.3.py", line 16, in <module>
    pi.set_mode(led_1, pigpio.OUTPUT)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1340, in set_mode

    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_MODES, gpio, mode))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 975, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))

pigpio.error: 'no permission to update GPIO
```

I have read many topics about this type of error but I didn't find a solution which worked for me. Please, if you could explain it to me in the simplest way I would very grateful.

Lionel.

Answer (score 0):

**pigpio only accepts Broadcom GPIO numbers.**

You will get an error message 'no permission to update GPIO' if you attempt to use a GPIO which is not present on the expansion header of your Pi.

On recent Pis with the 40 pin expansion header GPIO numbered 2-27 are available for use.  GPIO 0 and 1 are also available for use in certain circumstances.

Also see https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: In addition to this: looks to me that @Lionel is using physical pin numbers. Gpiozero uses BCM/Broadcom (the 'GPIO'  numbers in pinout)

Answer (score 0):

with the library RPi, I chose to use the BCM GPIO numbers. Now I am using the pigpio library I thought I had to use the broadcom GPIO numbers but in fact the BCM GPIO numbers works and it solves my previous issue.

Comment: Rather than edit this as a different user, post a new answer.  If you've lost the login credentials for this second user, either leave a comment here @goldilocks and I will delete it, or you can do this: *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)* (but it seems like a waste of time in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to generate my PWM trains triggered by a clock signal by combining the RPi and the pigpio library. My PWM trains are driving three differents leds which are thus emitting one after another.

In fact, I used the RPi library to generate the low frequency clock signal and to use the wait_for_edge function. Then I used the pigpio library to generate the higher frequency leds signal. See the code below :

```
import pigpio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time



GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pi = pigpio.pi()

clock=17
led_1=19
led_2=12
led_3=13


GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(clock, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(led_1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led_2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(led_3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)

clock_pwm = GPIO.PWM(18, 5)
clock_pwm.start(50)

pi.set_PWM_frequency(led_1,2000)
pi.set_PWM_frequency(led_2,2000)
pi.set_PWM_frequency(led_3,2000)
pi.set_PWM_frequency(14,2000)

GPIO.wait_for_edge(clock,GPIO.RISING)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_1,   0)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_2,   0)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_3,   0)
pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(14,   0)




while(1) :
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(clock,GPIO.RISING)
    pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_1,   25)
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(clock,GPIO.FALLING)
    pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_1,   0)

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(clock,GPIO.RISING)
    pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_2,   25)
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(clock,GPIO.FALLING)
    pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_2,   0)

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(clock,GPIO.RISING)
    pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_3,   25)
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(clock,GPIO.FALLING)
    pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(led_3,   0)

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(clock,GPIO.RISING)
    pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(14,   25)
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(clock,GPIO.FALLING)
    pi.set_PWM_dutycycle(14,   0)
```

I am still not fully satisfied because, when the rising edge is detected with the wait_for_edge function, the pwm signals which drive my leds, are starting with a random delay I would like them to start at a fixed delay. Any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks,

Lionel.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.